# assign output of execution of PHP script to a variable?

Tags: php, variables

I made a website, I probably didn't do it like I should have, but I was new to PHP at the time. So in order to save me lots of frustration of trying to re-write a script to display photos on my site, I need to run a *.php file, and make the output if it go into a var called "$html". I know it might sound strange, but that's what I need.

From inside index.php, I include photos.php; In photos.php, I need to declare $html with the *output* of a script called photos_page.php;

For example:
`$html = parse_my_script("../photos_page.php");`

Thank you

Comment: If you want to run it you could call it with curl and then use the output.

Comment: I need this feature to send the HTML to a web service that will generate a PDF. Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Answer:** 
To do that, you can use PHP's [Output buffering/control](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php). Here's some simple function that gets script output and returns it:

**Code:**

*Things used:* 
[`ob_start()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)
[`ob_get_clean()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)
[`is_readable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php)

```php
function getScriptOutput($path, $print = FALSE)
{
    ob_start();

    if( is_readable($path) && $path )
    {
        include $path;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if( $print == FALSE )
        return ob_get_clean();
    else
        echo ob_get_clean();
}
```

**Usage:**

```php
$path = '../photos_page.php';
$html = getScriptOutput($path);

if( $html === FALSE)
{
    # Action when fails
}
else
{
    echo $html;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your code works. however, *my* code is so not-cool, that I decided to just include() it from the main index.php file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php). This will place all output, that would normally be sent to the client, into a buffer which you can then retrieve:

```
ob_start();
include '../photos_page.php';
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

If you wish, you can place this functionality into a function to have it work as you described:

```
function parse_my_script($path)
{
    ob_start();
    include $path;
    $html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $html;
}
```

This, of course, assumes that your included file doesn't require the use of global variables.

For more information, check out all the output control functions:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

Comment: Hello! I am sorry, i didn't understand your question very well... I have the following PHP line: shell_exec("find ../ -name 'MY_FILE.pdf'") - I want to assign this output (Which returns a directory, with the location of the file) as a usable string to a var called $pdf_path ... I tried using your function but coul'nt figure out how to work with it...

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to try [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.yourwebsite.com/pages/photos_page.php");

//this will not work since it won't run through web server
//$html = file_get_contents("../photos_page.php");
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
ob_start();
require('../photos_page.php');
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `file_get_contents("http://yourdomain.com/path/to/photos_page.php")` for that.

---

**BUT:** If I were you, I would do it in this way:

**photos_page.php**

```
<?php

function get_photos_html() {
    $html = // generate html
    return $html;
}

?>
```

**main_file.php**

```
<?php

include('../photos_page.php');

$html = get_photos_html();

?>
```

Comment: Nope, he wants the script's *output*.

Comment: But _file_get_contents_ returns output!

Comment: @Kashiv: If I'm not mistaken, this function returns output only if you are fetching the php page through a web server. `file_get_contents("../photos_page.php")` won't work. In this case, you will be retrieving the file locally. Needs something like `file_get_contents("http://www.domain.com/photos_page.php")`

Comment: This unnecessarily creates a web request which uses many more resources than just simply using an output buffer.

Comment: @delnan is right. I do want the output. However, the whole stupid variable thing was not working right. Maybe because I was laoding "A" [index.html] which loads "B" [photos.php] which loads "C" [photos_page.php], and ... well it's too complicated to explain, I've decided to work it another way.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have a look at the method
ob_start() and ob_flush(), ob_get_contents(), etc.
http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

This will allow you to output data from your PHP file into a specific variable.

You should think about rewriting though of course :)

So basically:

```
ob_start();
include('yourfile.php');
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Output buffering** will hold outputted text in memory instead of actually outputting it to the response.

First, create a buffer by calling the `ob_start()` function.  When you are done storing output in the buffer, call `ob_get_clean()` to return the buffer contents and clear the buffer.

```
ob_start();
include "../photos_page.php";
$html = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you posted is pseudo code.

A code you wrote before and which didn't work out well shouldn't be used again. I would rewrite the parts you need and create some functions or even a class which you can use to get whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

If your `photos_page.php` works like this:

```
<?php
    // very basic code
    $img = "/path/to/my/image.jpg";
    echo '<img src="' . $img . '">' . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Then you could use:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://mysite.com/photos_page.php');
```

But really, you should re-write the code so you don't have to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this *if $path returns a value*:

```
$path = '/path/to/your/script.php';
$html = return include $path;
```